# SSH: SourceTree push fails

Tags: git, github, ssh, atlassian-sourcetree

While pushing code to master branch in a repo I found this message from sourceTree though **I have added public key in my github and generated private key and added in my pageant key list**.The message is :

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48

If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
```

[image]

I did not find any thing to write there. How can I solve it?

Comment: If you want to trust all certificates then just enter `"y"` and carry on.  If you want to install the repository's certificate then you will have to a bit more work.  What do you want to do?

Comment: I can not enter y there. there was no option to write.

Comment: No.  It prompted you with clear text, meaning that what you enter does not get echoed to the console (for security reasons--they don't want your clear text password to even be visible temporarily).  Just type `"y"` press enter and swallow the pill.

Comment: Issue still appears. And this is done through the UI of source tree - it prints the message, but does not provide input.

Comment: Warning March 2023:  "[**GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

Answer (score 1):

Apparently my sourcetree installation uses putty for the ssh connection. By trying to connect to the server in putty I could use input and add the key to the cache. After this the sourcetree push worked.

Answer (score 0):

One way to avoid seeing that with SourceTree is to pre-populate the `known_hosts` file in advance:

```
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
# on Windows, with `<git>/usr/bin` in the `%PATH%`
ssh-keyscan -H github.com >> %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts
```

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Comment: This doesn't work as well...

Comment: @AndriiKovalevskyi Than I would advise making a new question to describe your exact setup.