# Error "The authenticity of host 'github.com' can't be established. RSA key fingerprint "

Tags: github, fingerprint

I use my project at work, but I would like to work with him from home as I can log into my home machine to work with my project.

However, from home, I see the following message:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (ip)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

How can I get past it?

Comment: If you're ending up on this question in March 2023, it's likely because GitHub just updated their RSA key. Details on what to do here: https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/

Comment: @TreyHunner Good point, I have updated [my 2017 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)

Answer (score 98):

You should <del>simply be able to answer '`yes`'</del>, which will update your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file.

---

A better approach, to avoid any [MITM (Man-In-The-Middle) attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack), would be (as [commented below](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707922/error-the-authenticity-of-host-github-com-cant-be-established-rsa-key-finge/47708298#comment119644036_47708298) by [Mamsds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2379740/mamsds)) to verify GitHub's public key first (see "[GitHub's SSH key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints)") and, *if* you find a match, *then* you can answer 'yes'.

Example:

```bash
ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa github.com 2>&1 |ssh-keygen -lf -
256 SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s github.com (ECDSA)
```

---

After that, you can use a GitHub SSH URL (provided you have [generated the SSH public/private keys](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/), and registered the public one to your GitHub profile)

Note: the ssh key generation should use the base64 old PEM format (option `-m PEM`), rather than the new current 70 chars OpenSSH one.
See "[What is the correct format for private key in Credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53645530/6309)":

```
ssh-keygen -m PEM -t rsa -P "" -f afile
```

That or you can [switch to an HTTPS URL](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended).

---

Update March 2023:

## [GitHub updated their RSA SSH host key](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/)

> At approximately 05:00 UTC on March 24, out of an abundance of caution, we replaced our RSA SSH host key used to secure Git operations for GitHub.com.
>
> We did this to protect our users from any chance of an adversary impersonating GitHub or eavesdropping on their Git operations over SSH. This key does not grant access to GitHub’s infrastructure or customer data. This change only impacts Git operations over SSH using RSA.
> Web traffic to GitHub.com and HTTPS Git operations are not affected.
>
> Only GitHub.com’s RSA SSH key was replaced. No change is required for ECDSA or Ed25519 users
>
> If you see the following message when connecting to GitHub.com via SSH, then read onward.
>
> ```
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> @ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! @
> @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
> IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
> Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
> It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
> The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
> SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s.
> Please contact your system administrator.
> Add correct host key in ~/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
> Host key for github.com has changed and you have requested strict > checking.
> Host key verification failed.
> ```
>
> If you see the above message, you’ll need to remove the old key by running this command:
>
> ```
> $ ssh-keygen -R github.com
> ```
>
> Or manually updating your ~/.ssh/known_hosts file to remove the old entry.
>
> Then, you can manually add the following line to add the new RSA SSH public key entry to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file:
>
> ```
> github.com ssh-rsa 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
> ```
>
> Or automatically update GitHub.com’s RSA SSH key in your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`, by running the following in your terminal:
>
> ```bash
> $ ssh-keygen -R github.com
> $ curl -L https://api.github.com/meta | jq -r '.ssh_keys | .[]' | sed -e 's/^/github.com /' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
> ```

Or, without `jq`, for Mac or Windows users :

```
curl -L https://api.github.com/meta | grep ssh-rsa | \
  awk '{print "github.com", $2}' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

> You can verify that your hosts are connecting via our new RSA SSH key by confirming that you see the following fingerprint:
>
> ```
> SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s
> ```
>
> GitHub Actions users may see failed workflow runs if they are using `actions/checkout` with the ssh-key option.
> We are updating the `actions/checkout` action in all our supported tags, including `@v2`, `@v3`, and `@main`.
> If you pin the action to a commit SHA and use the ssh-key option, you’ll need to update your workflow. You can read more about this process in our [official documentation for Actions security hardening](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/security-hardening-for-github-actions#reusing-third-party-workflows).
>
> For more information, please visit our [official documentation on GitHub’s SSH public key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints).

So:

> ### What happened and what actions have we taken?
>
> This week, we discovered that GitHub.com’s RSA SSH private key was briefly exposed in a public GitHub repository.
>
> We immediately acted to contain the exposure and began investigating to understand the root cause and impact.
> We have now completed the key replacement, and users will see the change propagate over the next thirty minutes.
> Some users may have noticed that the new key was briefly present beginning around 02:30 UTC during preparations for this change.
>
> Please note that this issue was not the result of a compromise of any GitHub systems or customer information.
> Instead, the exposure was the result of what we believe to be an inadvertent publishing of private information. We have no reason to believe that the exposed key was abused, and took this action out of an abundance of caution.

---

As noted by [bk2204](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8705432/bk2204)'s[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75838005/6309):

> Some versions of OpenSSH include the host key for the IP address as well as for the hostname.
> This is rather unhelpful, as IP addresses can change with DNS, but hostname tend to be more stable.
>
> To remove the old key entirely:

```bash
# linux
sed -i -e '/AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31\/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi\/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# MacOS
sed -i '' -e '/AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31\/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi\/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts

# Windows
sed -i -e "/AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31\/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi\/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==/d" %USERPROFILE%\.ssh\known_hosts
```

The last command (for Windows) can be done with the `%PATH%` modified with:

```bash
set "GH=%ProgramFiles%\Git"
set "PATH=%GH%\bin;%GH%\cmd;%GH%\usr\bin;%GH%\mingw64\bin;%GH%\mingw64\libexec\git-core;%PATH%"
```

---

To remove any GitHub IP address from your `known_hosts` file, see [discussion 50878](https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/50878#discussioncomment-5420639):

> For anyone running into repeated `ECDSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP address / Offending key for IP` issues and you can't grep IPs in `known_hosts` because you have hashed entries, I have created a Gist listing all Github git IPv4 addresses (as of Fri Mar 24 16:33:22 UTC 2023), generated from CIDRs listed in https://api.github.com/meta:
>
> https://gist.github.com/a-abella/fb31a028943b804e8ada6cda4efbe9b6
>
> You can loop over these and feed them to `ssh-keygen -R`.
> A script with optional `known_hosts` file path argument is available here: https://gist.github.com/a-abella/9d6c91a56a892e4c74933d17d380aa01. The only dependency is `curl`.
>
> If you want a one-liner (though the standard you-shouldn't-pipe-scripts-from-the-internet warnings apply):
>
> ```
> curl -s https://gist.githubusercontent.com/a-abella/9d6c91a56a892e4c74933d17d380aa01/raw/0bcaef131f94e4938cb659d744c3019fd814643e/strip_github.sh | bash -s -- $HOME/.ssh/known_hosts
> ```

Comment: I think you should add a caveat about MITM attacks if you simply answer yes. A better approach should be verifying Github's public key first (from here: `https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints`) and if you find a match then you can answer yes.

Comment: @Mamsds Very good point, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Ok so... npm install is showing me a ECDSA key fingerprint in the format xx:xx:xx... but the above link gives me a different format, so I can't tell if it's a match or not!

Comment: @Michael I don't use `npm` to get a key fingerprint though. Only `ssh-keyscan -t ecdsa github.com 2>&1 |ssh-keygen -lf -`. Which does return `256 SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM github.com (ECDSA)`, as expected.

Comment: Thank you for updating with the March 2023 note from GitHub.  I was scratching my head about this until I saw your answer.

Comment: thank you. this answer will solve all the problem github causing

Answer (score 31):

Just add Github fingerprint to known hosts this way:

```bash
mkdir -p ~/.ssh
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: I had to create the folder as well `mkdir ~/.ssh`

Answer (score 24):

As you are attempting to connect to Github using SSH for the first time (no existing entry for Github in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` yet), you are being asked to verify the key fingerprint of the remote host. Because, if an intruder host represents itself as a Github server, it's RSA fingerprint will be different from that of a GitHub server fingerprint.

You have two options.

1. You may just accept, considering you don't care about the authenticity of the remote host (Github in this case), or,
2. You may verify that you are actually getting connected to a Github server, by matching the RSA fingerprint you are presented to (in the prompt), with [GitHub's SSH key fingerprints](https://help.github.com/articles/github-s-ssh-key-fingerprints/) in `base64` format.

The latter option is usually more preferable.

Comment: So why does the web page show them in base 64, but the key i'm being asked to compare from npm install is a sequence of hex digit pairs separated by colons?  How am I supposed to know if they are equal?

Answer (score 10):

## Use one of the following two solutions:

### 1) Set up the SSH key

Follow the steps discussed on [this](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) GitHub help page.

https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh

### 2) Clone using git with HTTPS

#### Type (copy/paste) the following commands in a terminal on the machine where you would like to clone the repository

```sh
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

#### You can revert this change using the following commands

```sh
git config --global url."git@github.com:".insteadOf https://github.com/
git config --global url."git://".insteadOf https://
```

Comment: Why `--global` and not `--local`?

Comment: Also this command will not really toggle the config, but each call will append one to the config.

Answer (score 7):

### Try these steps:

Open Git Bash

Check for existing SSH keys:

`$ ls -al ~/.ssh`

If you already have them, you will see:

> - id_rsa.pub
> - id_ecdsa.pub
> - id_ed25519.pub

If you don't, generate one (Press Enter to accept the default file location):

`$ ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"`

To copy the key to clipboard:

`$ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

Go to your account on Github/Settings/SSH and GPG keys/New SSH key

Paste your key there

Next, type:

`$ git remote`

If you see origin, remove it:

`$ git remote remove origin`

Continue with the last 2 steps provided on GitHub repo page...

`$ git remote add origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPONAME.git`

`$ git push -u origin master`

Refresh your GitHub repo page

Voila!

Comment: To copy the key to clipboard - 

`pbcopy < ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub`

Reference - https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

Comment: If you are not able to copy the key, just cat the file and copy the output.
`cat id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 5):

### 1- Create SSH key

if you don't have the ssh-key create it like this:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "youremail@example.com"
```

### 2- Check your SSH key

For this go to your folder ssh, example:

```
cd ~/.ssh
```

after that, run this command line : `ls`

if you have the files: **id_rsa**, **id_rsa.pub** so the all is good

now you need to copy your **id_rsa.pub** ! (**⚠️ NOT the id_rsa**)
for this run `cat id_rsa.pub` and copy the result

### 3- Github / Gitlab

1. Go to your github / gitlab.
2. Follow the step by your hosting:

- *github*: Click on your **profile** -> **Settings** -> **SSH and GPG Keys** -> **New SSH key**
- *gitlab*: Click on your **profile** -> **preferences** -> **SSH keys**

3. past your **id_rsa.pub** that you have already copied !

### 4- If you have already did it and it's already not working ??

When your enter your ssh-key in github / gitlab your key have a **Expiration date** so you just need to change it

That it ! Have a good work

Comment: This the answer. Also, if you've changed the name of your keys, just run `ssh-add xxx` where `xxx` is your new key name.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to type `yes` and it will work, for more information you can refer to the [Official Github documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection). This will give an output saying

```
Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Comment: probably op needs this happening automatically

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me

```
ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: It is considered safer to query the key from https://api.github.com/meta, as I document in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309). See also "**[Does `ssh-keyscan` verify the legitimacy of the host(s) it scans?](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/221614)**". (Hint: No. No, it does not)

Comment: @VonC your approach requires the `jq` module however... its not a builtin in mac unfortunately

Comment: @rv.kvetch Good point. I have edited [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309) to add an alternative *without* `jq`.