# Git Permission denied (publickey) when accessing server through Github Actions CI/CD

Tags: git, ubuntu, github, github-actions

When I connect to my server through my local computer I can successfully connect to Github using ssh.

I used [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) tutorial to setup the ssh keys.

However, when using Github actions I get this error:

```
err: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
err: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
err: 
err: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
err: and the repository exists.
```

This is my Github actions YML:

```
name: CI App to DO

on:
  push:
    branches: [master]
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]

jobs:
  deploy-do:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: SSH to server and Deploy App
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          port: ${{ secrets.SSH_PORT }}
          script: |
            cd ~/app
            git pull origin master
            npm run build
            pm2 restart next
```

When running ssh-add -l on the server through my local machine I get my key but when doing the same through the Github actions workflow I get:

```
The agent has no identities.
```

My server is hosted on a Digital Ocean Droplet using Ubuntu 20.04.
As stated previously, this works great when connecting to my server through my local machine and doing the git pull there. I use MobaXterm for connecting to my droplet.

---

**Edit:** I am able to make this work when not using a passphrase.

In my local machine i'm using MobaXterm

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey) help?

Comment: @ParthShah i've tried all that and still not working only on de CI workflow.

Comment: Your edit comment on working without a passphrase is the key here, I think. Are you talking about a passphrase on your SSH key? If so, which tool are you using - Putty or OpenSSH? And if using WIndows, are you using the credential manager? Please add that info in an edit...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since the passphrase seems to be the issue, you might need to add your key to the ssh agent in your GitHub Action workflow.
See as an example "[Using a SSH deploy key in GitHub Actions to access private repositories](https://www.webfactory.de/blog/use-ssh-key-for-private-repositories-in-github-actions)" from [Matthias Pigulla](https://twitter.com/mpdude_de), which proposes:

```
# .github/workflows/my-workflow.yml
# ... other config here
jobs:
    build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-18.04
        steps:
            -   uses: actions/checkout@v1

            -   name: Setup SSH Keys and known_hosts
                env:
                    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
                run: |
                    mkdir -p ~/.ssh
                    ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
                    ssh-agent -a $SSH_AUTH_SOCK > /dev/null
                    ssh-add - <<< "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}"

            -   name: Some task that fetches dependencies
                env:
                    SSH_AUTH_SOCK: /tmp/ssh_agent.sock
                run: ./fetch-deps.sh
```

But he has also defined since then [**actions/webfactory-ssh-agent**](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/webfactory-ssh-agent)

> This action
>
> - starts the ssh-agent,
> - exports the SSH_AUTH_SOCK environment variable,
> - loads a private SSH key into the agent and
> - configures known_hosts for GitHub.com.

Comment: I encountered the same issue using the same deployment file as in the question, honestly I don't know how to implement this solution, I have errors.

Comment: @nimondo That would be a good question on its own (with a link back to this answer) in order for you to explain your current problem.

Answer (score 10):

For this, you can add an extra step in your eas-pipeline.yml file after the Checkout step.

```
 - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

*******************************************************************************

      - name: Reconfigure git to use HTTP authentication
        run: >
          git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf
          ssh://git@github.com/
    

*******************************************************************************
```

Here's the original answer: https://github.com/actions/setup-node/issues/214

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Answer (score 0):

posting this for someone running on same issue, in my case, i was using cat my_key.pem to print and past the key to github secretes , the problem was it was not printing the whole key, messing the last line -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
so my workflow couldn't run (pemission denied: public key)
make sur to copy past the whole key, in my cas i used vim to display the key and past it to secrets , and it fixed the issue