# npm install not working for a particular module: async/each

Tags: npm, npm-install

A particular module is refusing to install. Here's the terminal snippet.

```
npm install async/each --save

The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.255.113)' can't be established.e7a8
RSA key fingerprint is SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8.
[..................] / rollbackFailedOptional: verb npm-session b237a7ec427fe7a8
```

It just hangs at that point. It never asks me if want to trust it anyway. Isn't this weird? Here's the page for the module. It's very popular.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-each

A [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707922/error-the-authenticity-of-host-github-com-cant-be-established-rsa-key-finge) asks about a similar issue but the user is asked if he wants to override. I am never asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to type

npm install async-each --save

(Note the replacement of the / with a -)