# Using a startup-script to clone a private Github repo?

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, ssh, google-compute-engine

I'm using a [startup-script](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts) on Google Cloud Compute.

The goal of the script is to clone a private repo from Github at startup time of the compute server.

To authenticate, I have a public deploy key for this one repo.  The private deploy key passed to the script at startup time.

```
... # Some action where the private key is passed in 

chmod u=rw,go= github_pri_deploy_key
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"  # Start ssh-agent in the background
ssh-add ${WORKING_DIR_PATH}/github_pri_deploy_key
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts
```

**The issue I'm running into is the `/root/.ssh/known_hosts` file is inaccessible during startup time.**

So I get an error in the logs saying `Host key validation failed.`

### What I tried

I've tried attempting creating the file manually but same issue since the root user couldn't create the file.

I was able to get the desired result of adding the Host key when after the machine starts up and I ssh into the machine and perform the task manually.

My `startup-script` is run as root, as is the only option on GCP Compute.  But if it's running as root, why can't ssh-keyscan append to the /root/ file?

This is the best I can illustrate since the repo is private.  Thank you.

Comment: I am posting a comment instead of an answer as I have not tested this recently. Git supports the environment variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`. If set, git will use the specified command for `git pull`. Try this in your startup script: `GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /path/to/private-key" git pull` Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git Make sure the permissions for the private key file are read-only (400).

Comment: @JohnHanley thank you!  I prefer not to use env variables but your answer actually gave me an idea to use this approach: 

`sudo -i mkdir /root/.ssh/; sudo touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts; ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com | sudo tee -a /root/.ssh/known_hosts`

Answer (score 2):

`Host key validation failed` is more about the known_hosts than the private key.

`ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com > /root/.ssh/known_hosts` should have taken care of it, provided `/root` is indeed used.

That is why using, for testing, `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` set to `ssh -Tv` would  give you an idea of what is actually used during your SSH commands, making sure your startup script was effective or not.

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---