# How to verify authenticity of host when fingerprint not in the same format that host provides you?

Tags: github, fingerprint

I was trying to do an npm install today and ran into an error that looks like this:

```
The authenticity of host 'github.com (140.82.114.3)' can't be established <trash due to npm overwriting part of the line>
ECDSA key fingerprint is xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx.
```

I have redacted the actual fingerprint but it was hex digits.  In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47707922/error-the-authenticity-of-host-github-com-cant-be-established-rsa-key-finge) some of the answers establish that you should verify the authenticity of this key [here](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints).  But when I go to this page I see keys in a totally different format:

- SHA256:nThbg6kXUpJWGl7E1IGOCspRomTxdCARLviKw6E5SY8 (RSA)
- SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM (ECDSA)
- SHA256:+DiY3wvvV6TuJJhbpZisF/zLDA0zPMSvHdkr4UvCOqU (Ed25519)

I'm assuming since the message I saw mentioned ECDSA I should be trying to compare it to the second value, but beyond this, how do I get this value in the xx:xx:xx... format?  You would assume that something important like this would be easy to compare so I'm a bit puzzled as to why there seems to be some excessive friction.

Answer (score 2):

The format you're seeing for your fingerprints is the legacy hex format using MD5.  Because MD5 is insecure and no longer suitable for use, since OpenSSH 6.8, fingerprints are printed using SHA-256 and base64.  SHA-256 is presently considered secure and is a good choice for a cryptographic hash function.

This probably means that you're using a very old version of OpenSSH, possibly on an unsupported operating system, such as CentOS 6.  If your OS is no longer supported, you should upgrade to one receiving security updates for everyone's benefit.

If in the meantime you still need to access GitHub, you can download the actual keys (as well as the fingerprints) from [the GitHub API](https://api.github.com/meta).  If you save the ECDSA key into a file, say `key`, then you can run `ssh-keygen -l -f key` and it will print the fingerprint for that key in a format you can use.