# Cloning of SSH-link from Github was denied

Tags: macos, github, ssh, repository, access-denied

Currently I have a problem that when I want to clone ssh-link from GitHub: it writes to me that permission denied (publickey).

I know exactly that before I accidentally wrote answer "No" on the question If I am sure to continue with connecting.

Please, how could I unblock it? I mean, to change to status - Yes, and then it could be working as well.

Comment: Did you resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The "yes/no" question the first SSH connection is normally the  one to add the remote host fingerprint to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

You can restore it with:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

(note the `>>`, *not* `>`, to *append to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file)

Compare the result of that command with the [official SSH host keys from GitHub](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-01-18-githubs-ssh-host-keys-are-now-published-in-the-api/), to make sure you are talking to the "right" github.com.

A [safer alternative to add those keys](https://serverfault.com/a/1098531/783), using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/):

```bash
curl --silent https://api.github.com/meta \
  | jq --raw-output '"github.com "+.ssh_keys[]' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

After that, if you still have a permission denied, make sure you have [added your public key to your GitHub SSH settings](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account).

[Test your connection](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/testing-your-ssh-connection) with `ssh -Tv github.com`: you should see a welcome message:

```
Hi username! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```