# How to run github action to deploy and build Node app on Digital ocean?

Tags: node.js, git, deployment, github-actions, digital-ocean

I'm trying to write github actions workflow with this steps:

1. Connect to Digital ocean over ssh
2. Navigate to `/saver` folder
3. Pull updates from `main` branch
4. Install dependencies and build project

My current code looks this way

```
name: Deploy app

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
      - name: Deploy to Digital Ocean
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
        with: 
          host: ${{secrets.SSH_HOST}}
          key: ${{secrets.SSH_KEY}}
          username: ${{secrets.SSH_USERNAME}}
          passphrase: ${{secrets.SSH_PASSPHRASE}}
          script: |
            cd saver 
            mkdir test #just to check if it connects and creates folder
        
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          ref: main

      - name: Pull changes
        run: git pull
         
      - name: Install client dependencies
        run: npm run client:prodinstall
                
      - name: Build client
        run: npm run client:build

      - name: Install server dependencies
        run: npm run server:prodinstall

      - name: Install server dependencies
        run: npm run server:build
```

As I see in logs in successfully logs to Digital ocean. On server I see folder `test`. but git pull doesn't work. I see

```
Run git pull
  
Already up to date.
```

But if I navigate by myself to DO server and run git pull I get new changes.

What's wrong?

**UPDATE:**

Current config

```
name: Deploy app

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]


jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04

    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          persist-credentials: false

      - name: Executing remote ssh commands using password
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
        env:
          SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
          GIT_SSH_COMMAND: 'ssh -Tv'
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          passphrase: ${{ secrets.SSH_PASSPHRASE }}
          script: |
            install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
            echo "${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
            host='github.com'
            hosts="$(dig +short "$host" | grep -v '\.$' | sed -z 's|\n|,|g')$host"
            ssh-keyscan -H "$hosts" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
            cd [appname]
            git pull origin main
            pm2 restart [appname]
         
      - name: Install
        run: npm run build
```

- I copied public key `cat .ssh/id_rsa.pub` and put it https://github.com/settings/keys
- Ran `nano .ssh/authorized_keys`
- Ran `chmod 700 .ssh/authorized_keys`
- Copied key from server with `cat .ssh/id_rsa`
- And saved it as secret **SSH_KEY** in repos settings
- Same with **SSH_USERNAME** and **SSH_HOST**

When I push repo I get this error

```
  " > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
host='github.com'
hosts="$(dig +short "$host" | grep -v '\.$' | sed -z 's|\n|,|g')$host"
ssh-keyscan -H "$hosts" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
cd [appname]
git pull origin main
pm2 restart [appname]

======END======
err: # 140.82.121.4:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-30fa67d5
err: # 140.82.121.4:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-30fa67d5
err: # 140.82.121.4:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-30fa67d5
err: # 140.82.121.4:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-30fa67d5
err: # 140.82.121.4:22 SSH-2.0-babeld-30fa67d5
err: git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
err: fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
err: Please make sure you have the correct access rights
err: and the repository exists.
```

Comment: `git pull` is running on the CI runner, not via SSH.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how to run it via ssh?

Comment: For debugging purposes, add in `ENV:` section a `GIT_SSH_COMMAND: 'ssh -Tv'`: that way, you will have more logs during the git pull.

Comment: @VonC updated code and error. So basically, that what we started from :)

Comment: OK, so apparently, the ssh-action does not take into account that variable...

Answer (score 1):

> how to run it via ssh?

You would need to include your `git pull` in the commands run by `appleboy/ssh-action@master`.

That means the `script` part of that action should include a `cd /path/to/repository`, and `git pull`.

For an SSH URL, that means you need to copy the private key to a GitHub secret (for instance: `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY`) and set it as an environment variable in your workflow file.
For example:

```yaml
- name: Executing remote ssh commands using password
  uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
  env:
    SSH_PRIVATE_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}
  with:
    host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
    username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
    port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
    script: |
      install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      echo "${{ secrets.SSH_PRIVATE_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
      host='github.com'
      hosts="$(dig +short "$host" | grep -v '\.$' | sed -z 's|\n|,|g')$host"
      ssh-keyscan -H "$hosts" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
      git pull origin main
```

---

Warning March 2023:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Comment: I tried this way already, but in this case it says 'git permission denied (publickey)'

Comment: @angelzzz What URL are you using from that `git pull`? HTTPS or SSH? You need to make sure your server (from which you are doing the pull) has the right credentials in place (private SSH key or cached token)

Comment: I use ssh git@github.com:[username]/[reponame].git. What approach I need to use in this case?

Comment: @angelzzz I have edited the answer to illustrate the proper step

Comment: I get the error 
ssh: handshake failed: ssh: unable to authenticate, attempted methods [none], no supported methods remain

Comment: uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.7
        env:
          SSH_KEY: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.SSH_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.SSH_USERNAME }}
          script: |
            install -m 600 -D /dev/null ~/.ssh/id_rsa
            echo "${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}" > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
            host='github.com'
            hosts="$(dig +short "$host" | grep -v '\.$' | sed -z 's|\n|,|g')$host"
            ssh-keyscan -H "$hosts" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
            cd project_name
            git pull origin main

Comment: @angelzzz It is best to edit your question to include your current configuration and error: it is easier to format and will be more readable than in a comment.