# RSA SSH host key from github changed?

Tags: git, github, ssh, rsa, ssh-keys

Recently github changed your ssh rsa host key. On the link https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/ its possible to find a solution for how to update your file, but it doesn't work in my case. I do the whole procedure, but another error appears that does not let me connect to the repository due to an error in connection security due to my fingersprinter being different from the requested fingersprinter

Comment: What is "another error"? What do you try? What do you expect? What happens instead? Please [edit] your post.

Answer (score 1):

Some versions of OpenSSH include the host key for the IP address as well as for the hostname.  This is rather unhelpful, as IP addresses can change with DNS, but hostname tend to be more stable.

To remove the old key entirely on Linux:

```
$ sed -i -e '/AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31\/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi\/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

On macOS, you need a slightly different invocation:

```
$ sed -i '' -e '/AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAABIwAAAQEAq2A7hRGmdnm9tUDbO9IDSwBK6TbQa+PXYPCPy6rbTrTtw7PHkccKrpp0yVhp5HdEIcKr6pLlVDBfOLX9QUsyCOV0wzfjIJNlGEYsdlLJizHhbn2mUjvSAHQqZETYP81eFzLQNnPHt4EVVUh7VfDESU84KezmD5QlWpXLmvU31\/yMf+Se8xhHTvKSCZIFImWwoG6mbUoWf9nzpIoaSjB+weqqUUmpaaasXVal72J+UX2B+2RPW3RcT0eOzQgqlJL3RKrTJvdsjE3JEAvGq3lGHSZXy28G3skua2SmVi\/w4yCE6gbODqnTWlg7+wC604ydGXA8VJiS5ap43JXiUFFAaQ==/d' ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Then you can do the following (from [the post](https://github.blog/2023-03-23-we-updated-our-rsa-ssh-host-key/)) to fill in the host keys:

```
$ curl -L https://api.github.com/meta | jq -r '.ssh_keys | .[]' | \
  sed -e 's/^/github.com /' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Comment: "$ curl -L https://api.github.com/meta | jq -r '.ssh_keys | .[]' | \
  sed -e 's/^/github.com /' >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts" doesnt work on windows

Comment: Then you can download the actual public key from the blog post and append it to your `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file (that is, the `.ssh/known_hosts` file in your home directory) with your preferred editor.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can edit your ~/.ssh/known_host and add at the bottom:

```
github.com ssh-rsa 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
```

It comes from the official page [GitHub's SSH key fingerprints](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/githubs-ssh-key-fingerprints).

That should be enough.

Comment: This gives me the following error: Warning: the RSA host key for 'github.com' differs from the key for the IP addre
ss '20.201.28.151'
Offending key for IP in /c/Users/Usuário/.ssh/known_hosts:11
Matching host key in /c/Users/Usuário/.ssh/known_hosts:12
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @JanioJunior Then the known_host issue should be OK. But you need to check what key is actually used: `ssh -Tv git@github.com`. What is your OS? Do you have registered a public key to your GitHub profile?

Comment: The github public key fingersprints: SHA256:uNiVztksCsDhcc0u9e8BujQXVUpKZIDTMczCvj3tD2s
My fingersprints after update github.com ssh-rsa:
SHA256:p2QAMXNIC1TJYWeIOttrVc98/R1BUFWu3/LiyKgUfQM
Curiously this is the fingersprint for ecdsa from github.